# ¿Es "a podrido" adjetivo o adverbio?

Tags: gramática

¿Es el término "a podrido" adjetivo o adverbio? La pregunta se basa en la siguiente oración:

> El mundo huele **a podrido** porque está decayendo.

Comment: *Podrido* es adjetivo.  Pero la frase preposicional está funcionando como adverbio, creo, modificando el verbo *huele*.

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2522/9385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"a podrido" es en realidad una frase preposicional. La pregunta sería si su función es adjetiva o adverbial.

El verbo "oler" puede estar seguido por adjetivo o adverbio.

- Huele bien / mal (adverbio).
- Huele fantástico / terrible (adjetivo).

Mi análisis es que "a podrido" proviene de "a que está podrido", donde "podrido" es adjetivo.

No obstante, en muchos casos "a" puede introducir un sustantivo, por ejemplo:

- Huele a pescado.
- Huele a rosas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!